# How to stop jQuery parser from converting array to object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, http-post

I have a javascript data file which looks like this:

```
data = { 
  items : [ 
   {name: 'ABC'}, 
   {name: 'CDF'} 
  ] 
}
```

When I pass in this data to `$.ajax(type: 'POST', data: data)` the converted data looks like this:

```
items[0][name]: 'ABC'
items[1][name]: 'CDF'
```

My problem is that the server I send this data to interprets this as:

```
items: { 
  '0' : { 'name' : 'ABC' }, 
  '1' : { 'name' : 'CDF' }     
}
```

The problem here is that `items` is treated as an object, not an array! 
So how do I make sure `$.ajax` encodes `items` as an array and not an object? Please and thank you!

Comment: What server do you send this too? Doesn't look like a js problem, and jQuery doesn't convert arrays to objects

Comment: Look at the converted data. It is an array with respect to js. But if the integer `0` was a string `'0'` it could easily be interpreted as an object.

Comment: I checked the documentation more. Setting `traditional` to true doesn't work either because the object is just sent as `object`. I want a mix of the current implementation with traditional for param serialization. But it might not be currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

can you do a little conversion afterward?

```html
data = { 
  items : [ 
   {name: 'ABC'}, 
   {name: 'CDF'} 
  ] 
}

data.items=Object.keys(data.items).map(key=>data.items[key])
```

Comment: I wish I could change how the server interprets the data. But I can't. I have to make sure the data I send is correct.

Comment: I see your format is x-www-form-urlencoded, then you need to serialize the data, try $.param(data)

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json'
})
```

should do the trick

Edited to add contentType that I erroneously left out as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I do have `dataType: 'json',` with the `POST` call.

Comment: Just tried it. Adding a contentType also throws an error on this server. I think it expects the data to be of the form `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`

Comment: @Yathl then the problem lies with your backend and how it parses the request data. You would need to update your question with what language you are using on the backend and how you are attempting to access the data

Comment: The backend is not under my control and it cannot be changed. It uses Ruby on Rails. The exact frontend is using Ember. Ember jQuery specifically. https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.Adapter/methods/shouldReloadAll?anchor=createRecord